# Generate random numbers Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to show a random numbers within my list. Im grabbing the list from the backend, and im just using these numbers as examples. This is my code, I'm not quite sure why its not filling in the  text.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $('.num-gen').text(number);
},
```

Made a **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EK6yG/1/)** to show you what I'm working with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open javascript console and see the syntax errors

Comment: You're ending with `},`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had an error in your code, you were missing the finishing `, 1000/*time in ms*/);`!

Also, jQuery is not required here, you may do this in Javascript like this.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    document.getElementsByClass('num-gen')[0].innerHtml = number;
}, 1000);
```

**EDIT:**

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.num-gen'),function(){
         var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
         jQuery(this).text(number);  
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear with my question. I meant, generate a different number for each listed item. Meaning each item will have a different number.

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax error in you code, change it to:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $('.num-gen').text(number);
}, 10);
```