# How to implement jQuery mobile swipe/shake in place of mouse swiping?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, touchscreen

I have managed to build a simple jQuery flash card game following an online tutorial, resulting in this code:

```
var eng2fr = {
from: null,
to: null,
suggester: {
    i: 0,
    words: [
        [ "beer", "binouze" ],
        [ "another beer", "une autre bière" ],
        [ "crazy", "fou" ],
        [ "What the heck?!", "c'est quoi ce délire" ],
        [ "whatever", "n'importe quoi"]
    ],
    next: function(){
        return this.words[ ( this.i++ ) % this.words.length ];
    }
},

init: function(el) {
    this.bindSwipe( $( "#display" ) );
    this.from = $( "#from" );
    this.to = $( "#to" );
    Events.listen( "card_next", $.proxy( this.next, this ) );
    Events.listen( "card_flip", $.proxy( this.flip, this ) );

    // Begin!
    this.next();
},

next: function() {
    var to = this.to,
        from = this.from,
        next = this.suggester.next(),
        _this = this;

    to.text( next[ 0 ] );

    to.addClass( "push in current" );
    from.addClass( "push out" ).one( "webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        from.text( next[ 1 ] );            
        from.removeClass( "current push out" );
        to.removeClass( "push in" );
        _this.from = to;
        _this.to = from;
    });
},

flip: function() {
    var to = this.to,
        from = this.from,
        _this = this;

    to.addClass( "flip in current" );
    from.addClass( "flip out" ).one( "webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        from.removeClass( "current flip out" );
        to.removeClass( "flip in" );
        _this.from = to;
        _this.to = from;
    });
},

bindSwipe: function( el ) {
    this.xStart = null;
    this.downEvent = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && navigator.appVersion.indexOf( 'iPhone OS ' ) > -1 ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
    this.upEvent =  'ontouchend' in document.documentElement && navigator.appVersion.indexOf( 'iPhone OS ' ) > -1 ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

    var _this = this;
    el.bind({
        "touchstart mousedown": function( e ) {
            if( e.type !== _this.downEvent ) return;
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.xStart = e.pageX && e.pageX > 0 ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageX;
        },
        "touchend mouseup": function( e ) {
            if( e.type !== _this.upEvent ) return;
            var newX = e.pageX && e.pageX > 0 ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageX;
            var diff = newX - _this.xStart;
            if( Math.abs( diff ) > 20) {
                if( diff > 0 ){
                    Events.trigger( "card_previous", {} );
                } else {
                    Events.trigger( "card_next", {} );
                }
            } else {
                Events.trigger( "card_flip", {} );
            }
        },
        "touchmove": function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

};

As you can probably see, this code relies on mouse events for flipping and browsing through cards. I'm looking to implement jQuery mobile swipe/tap functions in place of these and I was wondering if someone could help me with that or at least point me in the right direction.

Also, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to detect a shake event and use this to select a random "card" / word pair?

Comment: I prepared a demo for you to use swipe and tap events. however for the shake, that's on the hardware side of devices so i  think you need to use Phonegap/Cordova to access the sensors on a device eg(https://gist.github.com/leecrossley/4078996). demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/7q1mpLr2/

Comment: Thank you kindly @Tasos
Could you please guide me on how to do if I want dynamic information on both sides, i.e no static information on the "flipside".

Also, what would be the easiest way to implement some trigger (button, link) to pick a completely random card?

Last but not least, would it be possible to store the card contents in a simpler way, like a list of corresponding values? As all content, both front and back, will be simple one or two word phrases with uniform styling, it would be nice to keep things at a bare minimum for simplicity when creating new sets.

Comment: for dynamic content once you gather the data you use append eg ($("#card1").append(thedata);) -- http://api.jquery.com/append/ -- in JQM you may also need to enhance the data -- http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/ -- for random card you generate a random number then change to that card eg (    $.mobile.changePage("#card"+number , {transition: "slide");) -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414506/generate-random-numbers-jquery -- yes you can store data in number of ways, most common is an array --https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDrygdbNlbU